# Ensure that a list of URLs without a page part always ends with slash and dot

Tags: python

I have a really big list of URLs and I'd like to add a slash and dot (`/.`) to all URLs that don't have a page part. Here are some examples of what I'd like to achieve:

- `http://www.example.com` should be `http://www.example.com/.`
- `http://www.example.com/index.htm` is okay
- `http://www.example.com/.` is okay
- `http://www.example.com/#` should be `http://www.example.com/.`
- `http://www.example.com/something` should be `http://www.example.com/something/.`

One exception is that hashes (`#`) should be replaced with a dot too.

I could use regexs to do this because that's the only thing I that seems to pop into my head but since this is very big list 10000+ URLs, I'm looking for the fastest possible method.

Thanks

Comment: 10,000 isn't a big number to run on once. Is this a repeated task?

Comment: How do you now that `something` is a directory name?  It is very well possible that you mess up an URL by blindly appending a slash if it doesn't look like a filename.

Comment: HI Erisco. This is a repeated task. I'll be serving this data as JSON very often and on a different sets of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

By "page part" you seem to mean something with '.htm' on the end (given your 2nd and 5th examples), so:

```
url = url.rstrip('/#.')
if not url.endswith('.htm'):
    url += '/.'
```

Comment: `.html`, `.php`, `.asp`, etc..?

Comment: That list can get lengthy.  Unless you want to use something like `if '.' not in url.split('/')[-1]`.